# how to take the median every 12 monhts in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops, median

I have the following dataframe:

```matlab
x = randn(216,1)
```

How I can get the median every 12 months/rows?

I would need to get a 18x1 vector.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using a For-Loop and Incrmeneting By Chunk Size, 12

Grabs a chunk of the array one chunk at a time on each iteration. The partition of the array that is retrieved ranges from the value `Median_Index` and 11 following indices following it.

```
x = randn(216,1);
Median_Values = zeros(18,1);

Index = 1;
for Median_Index = 1: +12: 216

    Chunk = x(Median_Index: Median_Index + 11);
    Median_Values(Index) = median(Chunk,'all');
    Index = Index + 1;
end
```

Note: `all` *can be removed since we are dealing with a vector (specifically since it's 1D)* Thanks to **@Luis Mendo** for the suggestion and compatibility tips.

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: @Luis Mendo Thanks for the tip I heard it helps with Octave compatibility as well.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your data as a 12-column matrix, and then use [`median`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/median.html) with a second argument to specify that you want it to operate along the first dimension, that is, compute the median of each column:

```
x = randn(216, 1); % example data
N = 12; % chunk size
result = median(reshape(x, N, []), 1);
```

Comment: Perfect use of taking the median along a specific dimension!!!

Comment: @MichaelTr7 Thanks! I like things vectorized, even if loops are not as slow as they used to be...